# Parsing a email address in Salesforce

Tags: email, leads, contact

I'm not sure if this is possible but is there any way that I could parse an email address. So, I just want the domain of the email address where the "company.com" is so that I can use that to check if we already have that in our contacts. So when a new lead comes in, I can know that the company is already in our contacts. Any suggestions?

Comment: Split the email string at '@' delimiter using `split` method of string. This link describe how to use it - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Comment: I would use a formula field (`MID` function) so no apex is required

Comment: So use the MID function in a formula? Because I am going to create a workflow so if the company is already in our contacts then send out an email.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple regular expression in the [matcher](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm) class.  Probably something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/qT5zX2/1)

```
(?:.+)@(\S+)+
```

Comment: Alright, I will try this out